# Adjusting <td> length when entering data with jquery

Tags: jquery

When I try to enter data into the a cell with this code, the td cell that I want to type in gets stretched. how can I prevent this, and keep it at normal size? 
if you try to enter a value in any of the cells on the table, you will better understand what I mean. Thanks.

Jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/cw3rojpz/

```
HTML:
<table>
<tr><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $("td").dblclick(function () {
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
        $(this).children().first().focus();

        $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var newContent = $(this).val();
                $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
            }
        });

    $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
table {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #8ab6d1; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
} 

table td {
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #8ab6d1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the width of your input box, like:

```
input[type=text]
{
 width: 50px;
}
```

Check here https://jsfiddle.net/cw3rojpz/2/

Comment: Thanks, PM. I tried width for td itself but it didn't work. I understand now. it works.